# Regex to get whatever the parent directory of my file is in string file path

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string file path and I am looking to get the name of the folder that is next up from the file.

Here is my file path:

```
Test/FilePathNeeded/testing.txt
```

I am sure there is a way to get `FilePathNeeded` from the file path above with regex, I just am not sure how it would be done. My thought is that the amount of directories that `testing.txt` is in should not matter, but the folder needed would always be one up from the file.

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if it doesn't. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Is is a requirement that you use regex for this?

Comment: @TomFenech - I guess it doesn't have to be, I was just looking for the most efficient way to do so.

Comment: What about `var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName("Test/FilePathNeeded/testing.txt");` ?

Comment: @EZI, that will return `"Test/FilePathNeeded`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Regex, You can use:

```
string directory = new DirectoryInfo(
                               Path.GetDirectoryName("Test/FilePathNeeded/testing.txt")
                                    ).Name;
```

`Path.GetDirectoryName` will return `Test/FilePathNeeded` that you can use in the constructor of `DirectoryInfo` and get `Name`.

Another option is to use `Directory.GetParent` like:

```
var directory  = Directory.GetParent("Test/FilePathNeeded/testing.txt").Name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use:

```
var dir = new FileInfo("Test/FilePathNeeded/testing.txt").Directory.Name;
```

This will return `FilePathNeeded`

Answer (score 1):

Use the FileInfo class:

```
  var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"Test/FilePathNeeded/testing.txt");
  var directoryInfo = fileInfo.Directory;
  var parentDirectoryName = directoryInfo.Name;
```